# Testing Custom Bootstrappers in Nancy

Tags: c#, testing, mstest, bootstrapper, nancy

So I have a `CustomBootstrapper`, which does a lot of application initialization, including IoC registration and Quartz scheduler setup. The modules also heavily rely on the `SuperSimpleViewEngine`.

Now I need to test this, using MSTest of course, and as everyone has probably figured out by now this is not going to work. The Nancy guys figured this out early, and have provided this workaround : https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Nancy-Testing-View-Location which I assume works, because when I in my test case try to create an instance of my bootstrapper it fails miserably, because there are more than one RootPathProviders.

So the solution, it would seem is to use a ConfigurableBootStrapper. So I guess the only question is, how do I make sure that the ConfigurableBootStrapper is setup the same way as my `CustomBootStraper`?

Comment: There is no other works to do in the test project. Following your link, add a class implementing `IRootPathProvider` in the test project, in the test code, write `var bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();`, Nancy will handle the view path for us.

Answer (score 1):

In your tests, create a test bootstrapper, which inherits from your custom one, then override only the functionality which breaks. Use that test bootstrapper for tests, assuming that your overrides are minimal.

Answer (score 1):

```
        var browser = new Browser(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.RootPathProvider<YourRootPathProvider>();
            cfg.Module<YourModule>();
        });
```